# Idea for finding the SQL Server instances using Powershell Script

Tags: sql-server, powershell, amazon-ec2

Description: I have one window server in which different versions of MS SQL servers are running and when I ran below power shell script it displays below result but I need to add SQL Server version like with name as SQL Server 2014, SQL Server 2008 ...

I am running below PowerShell script to get the details

```
[System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator]::Instance.GetDataSources()
```

PowerShell script output:

```
ServerName          InstanceName         IsClustered       Version
----------          ------------         -----------       -------------
hostname1                                   No             11.0.3000.0
hostname2           RAMTEST                 No             11.0.3000.0
```

I need to add one more column with SQL Server name based on version. Please suggest

Comment: You only want to transform the output?

Comment: Yes i need to list out all the MS SQL instances name, Version and Name  like  eg: host1   Instance name (Default or Named instance)  11.0.3000  SQL Server 2012 like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below.. You can add the other two columns, as needed. I removed them due to nulls. But feel free to check for NULLs and replace with any value you see fit. I have tested it and it works.

```
$ServerList  = [System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator]::Instance.GetDataSources() | Select ServerName, IsClustered, Version, InstanceName

$ServerList | foreach { 
$i = $i - 1
    if ($_.Version -like "14.0.*" )         { $Versionresult ="SQL Server 2017"   }  
elseif ($_.Version -like "13.0.*" )         { $Versionresult ="SQL Server 2016"   } 
elseif ($_.Version -like "12.0.*" )         { $Versionresult ="SQL Server 2014"   }
elseif ($_.Version -like "11.0.*" )         { $Versionresult ="SQL Server 2012"   }  
elseif ($_.Version -like "10.50.*")         { $Versionresult ="SQL Server 2008 R2"}  
elseif ($_.Version -like "10.00.*")         { $Versionresult ="SQL Server 2008"   }
elseif ($_.Version -like "9.00.*" )         { $Versionresult ="SQL Server 2005"   } 
elseif ($_.Version -like "8.00.*" )         { $Versionresult ="SQL Server 2000"   } 

$table = [PSCustomObject] @{"ServerName" = $_.ServerName ; "IsClustured" = $_.IsClustered ;"Version" = $Versionresult ;"InstanceName" = $_.InstanceName}
$table

}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Getting Below output Name                           Value
----                           -----
Hostname1                SQL Server 2012
Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Hostname1'  Key bei
ng added: 'Hostname1'"
At C:\test\SQL_instances.ps1:14 char:10
+ $hash.add <<<< ($_.ServerName, $Versionresult)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Hostname1                SQL Server 2012              .............Please suggest Rahim

Comment: Are you at least getting the list and a few servers are failing with the above exception.. Can you run it from you IDE as a script first rather than executing the .ps1 file